# Django: How to Get the Result of a Raw SQL "COUNT(*)" Query?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, full-text-search

I have a table of keywords that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `keywords` ( 
    `keyword` VarChar( 48 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `id` Int( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    `blog_posts_fulltext_count` Int( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) )
```

I also have a table of blog posts that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_posts` ( 
    `id` Int( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    `title` LongText CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL,
    `summary` LongText CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) );

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX `title_summary_fulltext` ON `blog_posts`( `title`, `summary` );
```

As you can see, I have a full text index on the fields `title`, `summary` in `blog_posts`.

The following search works correctly:

```
select count(*) from blog_posts where match(title,summary) against ('paid');
```

Now I'd like to populate the field `keywords.blog_posts_fulltext_count` with the number of rows in `blog_posts` that the `keyword` appears in.

When I run this:

```
keywords = Keywords.objects.all()
for the_keyword in keywords:
    query = "select count(id) from BlogPosts where match(title,summary) against ('{0}')".format(the_keyword.keyword)
    number_of_mentions = blog_posts.objects.raw(query)
    for obj in number_of_mentions:
        a = obj
```

...the RawQuerySet `number_of_mentions` appears to return without errors, and `number_of_mentions.query` contains:

```
 'select count(id) from blog_posts where match(title,summary) against ('paid')'
```

But when the code runs the `for obj in number_of_mentions` line, it throws:

> raise InvalidQuery('Raw query must include the primary key')

I've also tried defining the query string as:

```
query = "select count('id') from BlogPosts where match(title,summary) against ('{0}')".format(the_keyword.keyword)
```

...and as:

```
query = "select count(*) from BlogPosts where match(title,summary) against ('{0}')".format(the_keyword.keyword)
```

...with the same error message resulting.

What is the correct way to get a result from a raw sql `COUNT` command in Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `blog_posts.objects.raw()`, Django expects the raw query to somehow return `blog_posts` objects. But your count query will return a single number instead of a collection of objects. That's the API you see documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw).

If you want to run a query that will not return model objects, but something different (like a number), you have to use the method described in another section of that same page — [Executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

The general idea is that you'll have to use a *cursor* (something that iterates over a database resultset) and get it's only result. The following example should give you an idea of how to do it.

```py
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("select count(id) from BlogPosts where match(title,summary) against (%s)", [the_keyword.keyword])
    # get a single line from the result
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    # get the value in the first column of the result (the only column)
    count_value = row[0]
```